# Zip Files Automatically - Using .bat File

Tags: zip, 7zip

I am using Oracle EXPDB to export the database. I will get the dmp file for around 50GB. Once dmp file generated i will manually zip that. But i need to do that automatically from batch (.bat) file.  I had tried with this code,

```
   7z a -t 7z -r "D:\backup.zip" "D:\MyStuff\*.*"
```

Also, installed 7Zip related things. But still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the correct answer.

Download 7za.exe and put in C:/Windows/System32.

//Export database

```
expdp username/password@sid DUMPFILE=Test.dmp TABLES=movement
```

//Zipping the dmp file

```
7za a -tzip "I:\Test.zip" "I:\Test.dmp"
```

//Deleting the Original File, after zipping

```
del "I:\Test.dmp"
```

Comment: Although that works I wouldn't recommend manually adding files to the System32 folder. Better to stick the 7za.exe in another non-system location, or simply with your batch file.

Comment: I'm curious as you removed the *.* in the files to be zipped. I wonder is it still possible to maybe specify "*.dmp" to grab all dmp files within the directory and place them in the same "Test.zip"